# My component template can't find value property from <script> VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, templates, vue-component

So for some reason my app doesn't read my value variable that was defined in data. Not sure what's going on. Npm compiles this without any errors.

Here's the fiddle with my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/invinivi/yr164pb7/

```js
<template>
  <div id="exercise">
    <div>
      <p>Current Value: {‌{ value }}</p>
      <button @click="value += 5">Add 5</button>
      <button @click="value += 1">Add 1</button>
      <p>{‌{ result }}</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text">
      <p>{‌{ value }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Ex3',
        el: '#exercise',
        data: function () {
            return {
                value: 0
            }
        },
        computed: {
            result: function () {
                return this.value == 37 ? 'done' : 'not there yet';
            }
        },
        watch: {
            result: function () {
                var vm = this;
                setTimeout(function () {
                    vm.value = 0;
                }, 5000);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

```html
// FILE - Ex3.vue

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Ex3/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Ex3 from "./components/Ex3"

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Ex3
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: To be precise - my app displays "{{ value }}" and "{{ result }}" instead of number

Comment: Hmm i copy pasted your code to codesandbox and it's showing "{{ value }}" too, idk why. Then i deleted the text and rewrite "{{ value }}" and suddenly it's working, here: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-pasteur-fotii?file=/src/components/Ex3.vue

Comment: I checked on UTF-8 encoder here: https://mothereff.in/utf-8 , and it's showing your double curly bracket encoded to `\x7B\xE2\x80\x8C\x7B` meanwhile the correct curly bracket supposed to be `\x7B\x7B`, i don't know what's going on with your curly bracket lol, it has extra `\xE2\x80\x8C` between the `\x7B` which based on https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128&utf8=string-literal , it means `ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER`

Comment: o_O How do i change that in IntelliJ? Any clues?

Comment: Alright, sorted it out. It was problem with my windows keyboard settings. So the code works, that the most important thing. Thank YOU Owl for helping me out! <3

Comment: There is only 1 user replied to your comment.. but np!

Answer (score 0):

The curly brackets had wrong encoding through Windows settings. After changing the settings to utf-8, everything runs fine.